# Is there any assessment which could be performed before making a decision to consider VMSS for an application?

Tags: azure-vm-scale-set

I have referred the following document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-design-overview

It just lists VM and VMSS features. What I am looking for is any guidance from the application perspective. Eg: If the application is stateless then VMSS can be consider .. something on those lines.

Any help to collect such questions / assessment or guidance to consider VMSS would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I will give you some perspectives that I think you need to focus on:

1. if you will change the VM instances frequently, it's not good to use VMSS, you'd better use the VM first to make a certain VM image.
2. If you just need to use VM and it's enough to keep your application, then it's not good to use VMSS, VM is better.
3. All the instances of the VMSS have the same configuration, if you want different configurations for the instances, then it's not good to use VMSS.

These are the perspectives you need to think about before you decide to use VMSS.